# Preserve the word list numbering in MS word programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

There is a word document containing list from 1 to 10. I have divided it into two word documents - one containing list items from 1 to 5 and other containing list items from 6 to 10 programmatically. However,in second document, the numbering is not preserved. I am getting list item numbers 1 to 5 in second document. I want them to be 6 to 10.

Comment: Start the numbering in the second document at 6?  I doubt that "preserve numbering" works across multiple word documents.

Comment: It's not always the same that I have to divide in 5. I have to divide on some conditions

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to figure out where to divide, since I'm pretty sure the "preserve numbering" doesn't work across multiple documents.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Robert that "preserve numbering" doesn't work across Word documents. Maybe you could build a new property like ListNumberingStartValue in the second Word.

Comment: How can I? Can you please show help me with some sample?